# Which pre-processing step is good for my dataset?

Tags: image, image-processing, computer-vision, deep-learning

I have a training dataset of images. These images have ranged from 0-2500. However, in my testing dataset, some image has ranged from 200-3000. My question is which pre-processing step will good for that kind of data:

1. Normalization to zero mean and unit variance
2. Normalization to [0,1]
3. Convert to Range 0-2500 by normalize [0,1] and then multiply with 2500

Thanks all

Comment: Your only choice is to experiment and see which one works better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data you feed into your neural network should resemble your test data set as close as possibe. This is often done with normalization, because then the values are often closesly related in similar images. However this can not be said in general and does depend on your use-case. For a general rule of thumb i would adivse you to look at: http://ufldl.stanford.edu/wiki/index.php/Data_Preprocessing

Comment: Thanks, Thomas Pinetz. You are totally right and I truly agree with you that training and testing range must be close as much as possible. However, in my case, the testing data has different range `[200,3000]` in comparison with `[0,2000]`. Do you think the option 2 or 3 is better? Because they are same method to normalize image

Comment: I would start with option 2 personally. If the testing error is not where it should be I would try option 1 as a substitute.

Comment: Thanks. some papers refer the option 1 than option2. Thanks for your help. In the course of stanford, it also use option 1

Comment: That is because of the interaction between a normalized training set and batch normalization. Batch normalization expects a 0 mean unit variance training set. However I recently got better performance by using 0-1 normalization for my use case even though I made heavy use of batch normalization.

Comment: Thanks for sharing that information. Right, I also using BN layer in my network. I will try normalize 0-1 as you suggestion